# deeplinking from assistant action to android app

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have made a few actions for google assistant with dialogflow using external webhook. Now I am trying to provide a deep link to my app so that a user can go from the action to my android app on clicking a button or link out the suggestion. I have tired by providing the deep link as the specified format of intent://etc but still I am being shown error in the actions simulator. Can someone please help me out? Is this actually possible now in actions on google/dialog flow?

Comment: You should start here https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html and then ask a follow-up if you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but [as far as I know it's not possible](https://plus.google.com/+MartinDluhos/posts/9toRTvY6tLQ) to let one action call any other action. The only thing you can probably do is to link to the entry in the Google Assistant Catalogue like https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000d78c2695d3?hl=en for example and make that [a LinkOutSuggestion](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chips).